# ValueError: no such test method in <class 'myapp.tests.SessionTestCase'>: runTest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test case:

```
class LoginTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

I'd like to use it in a different test case:

```
class EditProfileTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def __init__(self):
    self.t = LoginTestCase()
    self.t.login()
```

This raises:

```
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'LoginTest: runTest`
```

I looked at the unittest code where the exception is being called, and it looks like the tests aren't supposed to be written this way. Is there a standard way to write something you'd like tested so that it can be reused by later tests? Or is there a workaround?

I've added an empty `runTest` method to `LoginTest` as a dubious workaround for now.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

`unittest` does deep black magic -- if you choose to use it to run your unit-tests (I do, since this way I can use a very powerful battery of test runners &c integrated into the build system at my workplace, but there are definitely worthwhile alternatives), you'd better play by its rules.

In this case, I'd simply have `EditProfileTestCase` derive from `LoginTestCase` (rather than directly from `unittest.TestCase`). If there are some parts of `LoginTestCase` that you do want to also test in the different environment of `EditProfileTestCase`, and others that you don't, it's a simple matter to refactor `LoginTestCase` into those two parts (possibly using multiple inheritance) and if some things need to happen slightly differently in the two cases, factor them out into auxiliary "hook methods" (in a "Template Method" design pattern) -- I use all of these approaches often to diminish boilerplate and increase reuse in the copious unit tests I always write (if I have unit-test coverage < 95%, I always feel truly uneasy -- below 90%, I start to feel physically sick;-).

Comment: How does it answer the question? Did he ask about virtue of good coverage? Why don't tell about how to "play by its rules"? "deep black magic" indeed!?

Comment: Scroll down, this is the least useful answer by far.

Answer (score 28):

The confusion with "runTest" is mostly based on the fact that this works:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_001(self):
        print "ok"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

So there is no "runTest" in that class and all of the test-functions are being called. However if you look at the base class "TestCase" (lib/python/unittest/case.py) then you will find that it has an argument "methodName" that defaults to "runTest" but it does NOT have a default implementation of "def runTest"

```
class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
```

The reason that unittest.main works fine is based on the fact that it does not need "runTest" - you can mimic the behaviour by creating a TestCase-subclass instance for all methods that you have in your subclass - just provide the name as the first argument:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_001(self):
        print "ok"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for method in dir(MyTest):
       if method.startswith("test"):
          suite.addTest(MyTest(method))
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: You may want to check to make sure `method` is indeed a function inside the `for` loop, a property such as `test_name="foo"` may be a false positive here

Answer (score 27):

Here's some '**deep black magic**':

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test_MyTests)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
```

Very handy if you just want to test run your unit tests from a shell (i.e., [IPython](http://ipython.org/)).

Comment: Besides what happens, that's the actual solution to the problem I had! Not sure why it's "down here" instead of the top! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind editing unit test module code directly, the simple fix is to add under **case.py** class **TestCase** a new method called runTest that does nothing.

The file to edit sits under pythoninstall\Lib\unittest\case.py

```
def runTest(self):
    pass
```

This will stop you ever getting this error.

Comment: This works also by adding these lines of code directly in your `unittest.TestCase` sub-class

Answer (score 6):

Guido's answer is almost there, however it doesn't explain the thing. I needed to look to `unittest` code to grasp the flow.

Say you have the following.

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def testA(self):
    pass

  def testB(self):
    pass
```

When you use `unittest.main()`, it will try to discover test cases in current module. The important code is `unittest.loader.TestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase`.

```
def loadTestsFromTestCase(self, testCaseClass):
  # ...

  # This will look in class' callable attributes that start 
  # with 'test',  and return their names sorted.
  testCaseNames = self.getTestCaseNames(testCaseClass)

  # If there's no test to run, look if the case has the default method.
  if not testCaseNames and hasattr(testCaseClass, 'runTest'):
    testCaseNames = ['runTest']

  # Create TestSuite instance having test case instance per test method.
  loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))

  return loaded_suite
```

What the latter does, is converting test case class into test suite, that holds the instances of the class per its test method. I.e. my example will be turned into `unittest.suite.TestSuite([MyTestCase('testA'), MyTestCase('testB')])`. So if you would like to create a test case manually, you need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

@dmvianna's answer got me very close to being able to run `unittest` in a jupyter (ipython) notebook, but I had to do a bit more. If I wrote just the following:

```
class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule (TestStringMethods)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I got

> ---
>
> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK

It's not broken, but it doesn't run any tests! If I instantiated the test class

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule (TestStringMethods())
```

(note the parens at the end of the line; that's the only change) I got

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule (TestStringMethods())
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.pyc in **init**(self, methodName)
>       189         except AttributeError:
>       190             raise ValueError("no such test method in %s: %s" %
>   --> 191                   (self.**class**, methodName))
>       192         self._testMethodDoc = testMethod.**doc**
>       193         self._cleanups = []
>
> ValueError: no such test method in : runTest

The fix is now reasonably clear: add `runTest` to the test class:

```
class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        test_upper (self)
        test_isupper (self)
        test_split (self)

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule (TestStringMethods())
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

> ---
>
> Ran 3 tests in 0.002s
>
> OK

It also works correctly (and runs 3 tests) if my `runTest` just `pass`es, as suggested by @Darren.

This is a little yucchy, requiring some manual labor on my part, but it's also more *explicit*, and that's a Python virtue, isn't it?

I could not get any of the techniques via calling `unittest.main` with explicit arguments from here or from this related question [Unable to run unittest's main function in ipython/jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895781/unable-to-run-unittests-main-function-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook) to work inside a jupyter notebook, but I am back on the road with a full tank of gas.

Comment: in the `runTest` method, did you mean to say `self.test_upper()` instead of `test_upper(self)`?