# UnitTest in Python

Tags: python, testing, subclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ValueError: no such test method in <class 'myapp.tests.SessionTestCase'>: runTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090479/valueerror-no-such-test-method-in-class-myapp-tests-sessiontestcase-runtest)

```
import unittest

class BzTestSe(unittest.TestCase):
    DEFAULTUSERNAME = 'username-a2'
    DEFAULTPASSWORD = 'pass'
    DEFAULTHOST = 'localhots'

    def __init__(self,username=DEFAULTUSERNAME, password=DEFAULTPASSWORD, host=DEFAULTHOST):
        super(unittest.TestCase,self).__init__()
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.host=host

class test_se_topwebsite(BztTestSe):
    def setUp(self):
        print "setup"

    def test_test_se_topwebsite(self):
        self.fail()
```

When I call the above class from another file,I get the following error. Please let me know where I am wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "testsuite/test_se.py", line 10, in __init__
    super(unittest.Testcase,self).__init__()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 184, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'testsuite.test_se.BztTestSe'>: runTest
```

Comment: "call the above class"?  What does this mean?

Comment: Sorry am a newbie to python. I invoked this class from another file but it throws this error

Comment: show us the exact code you use in the other file to invoke the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try and go back to something simple. In using unittest you have a couple of ways to execute your test cases but the simplest way is to have a main function in the file that contains your unittests.

For example:

```
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.message = "does this work"

    def test_message_is_expected(self):
        self.assertEquals("does this work", self.message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Note your test cases (classes) sub class unittest.TestCase, you then use a setUp method to set any state for your test cases, and finally you'll want some methods prefixed test_ ... which the test runner will execute.

If you saved the above file into lets say test_something.py and then in a console ran python test_something.py you'd see the results of the test output to the console.

If you can re cast your example into something a little clearer using this pattern rather than the inheritance hierarchy you've used you may be able to execute your tests.

I realise this is more of a comment than an answer but I can't yet make comments.

Comment: It's a bit long for a comment anyway :)