# Python: no such test method: How can I execute a test method by calling it explicitly from another method?

Tags: python, flask

Here is my `LoginResourceHelper` Test class

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
    class LoginResourceHelper(TestCase):
        content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        def test_create_and_login_user(self, email, password):
            user = UserHelper.add_user(email, password)
            self.assertIsNotNone(user)

            response = self.client.post('/', content_type=self.content_type,
                                        data=UserResourceHelper.get_user_json(
                                            email, password))
            self.assert200(response)
            # HTTP 200 OK means the client is authenticated and cookie
            # USER_TOKEN has been set

            return user

    def create_and_login_user(email, password='password'):
        """
        Helper method, also to abstract the way create and login works.
        Benefit? The guts can be changed in future without breaking the clients
        that use this method
        """
        return LoginResourceHelper().test_create_and_login_user(email, password)
```

When I call `create_and_login_user('test_get_user')`, I see error as following

```
 line 29, in create_and_login_user
    return LoginResourceHelper().test_create_and_login_user(email, password)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'core.expense.tests.harness.LoginResourceHelper.LoginResourceHelper'>: runTest
```

Comment: Change `LoginResourceHelper()` to `LoginResourceHelper`

Comment: TypeError: unbound method test_create_and_login_user() must be called with LoginResourceHelper instance as first argument when I do that

Comment: I'm thinking you need to instantiate the class first, since the calling function is outside of the class.  Something like `self._loginHelper = LoginResourceHelper` then change your return to `return self._loginHelper.test_create_and_login_user(email, password)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python's `unittest` module (which Flask is using behind the scenes) organizes the code in a special way.

In order to run a *specific* method from a class that is derived of `TestCase` you need to do the following:

```
LoginResourceHelper('test_create_and_login_user').test_create_and_login_user(email, password)
```

---

### What untitest does behind the scenes

In order to understand why you must do this, you need to understand how the *default* `TestCase` object works.

Normally, when inherited, `TestCase` is expecting to have a `runTest` method:

```
class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
       # Do assertions here
```

However if you needed to have multiple `TestCases` you would need to do this for every single one.

Since this is a tedious thing to do, they decided to the following:

```
class ExampleTestcase(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        # Do assertions here

    def test_bar(self):
        # Do other assertions here
```

This is called a *Test Fixture*. But since we did not declare a `runTest()`, you now must specify what method you want the TestCase to run - which is what you want to do.

```
>>ExampleTestCase('test_foo').test_foo()
>>ExampleTestCase('test_bar').test_bar()
```

Normally, the `unittest` module will do all of this on the back end, along with some other things:

- Adding TestCases to a Test Suite (which is normally done by using a TestLoader)
- Calling the correct TestRunner (which will run all of the tests and report the results)

But since you are circumventing the normal `unittest` execution, you have to do the work that `unitest` regularly does.

For a really indepth understanding, I *highly recommend* that you read the docs [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code).