# python nose `ValueError: no such test method in <class 'my_test.check_error_test'>: runTest`

Tags: python, nose, nosetests, python-unittest

I have a working test suite that runs with Nose.

I recently realized I needed to add things to my overall `setUp()`, as triggered by a variable found in each individual test (the variable gets updated by our version control system).

I have added an `__init__()` to my BaseTest.py and my individual test.  However, I get `ValueError: no such test method in <class 'my_test.check_error_test'>: runTest`

From googling, it looks like this has to do with a unittest loader.  But Nose always took care of all of the loaders before.

I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that I am touching the `methodName` attribute after Nose sets it, but I cannot figure out what I should be setting it to, ESPECIALLY since I use various Nose Plugins.  Or perhaps there's a better way.  What do I need to do differently?

BaseTest.py

```
import unittest

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', p4rev=None):
        super(BaseTest, self).__init__(methodName)
        self.p4rev = p4rev

    def setUp(self):
        triggerSomething(p4rev)
```

My_test.py

```
from BaseTest import BaseTest

rev = '12345'

class CheckError_Test(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self, rev):
        super(CheckError_Test, self).__init__(p4rev=rev)

    dosomething()
```

**NOTE:** If I don't have use `super(BaseTest, self).__init__(methodName)` I get an error: `Attribute error: 'check_error_test' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'`.  Hence its inclusion

**To Clarify:** One comment suggests duplicate post, however linked post is about how to run tests in general, while this post asks how to access specific variables within a given test at runtime.

Comment: If `rev` is present in `My_test.py`, why can't you just access it as a global variable, rather than trying to embed it into the test classes?

Comment: Seems like that would result in cyclic dependency.  `Bast_Test` class needs `my_test.rev` for its `setUp()`.  But `my_test` needs `Bast_Test.setUp()` in order to run...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: no such test method in <class 'myapp.tests.SessionTestCase'>: runTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090479/valueerror-no-such-test-method-in-class-myapp-tests-sessiontestcase-runtes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use built in [attributes plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) to pass the information down:

in my_test.py:

```
from base_test import BaseTest
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

rev = '12345'

@attr(rev=rev)
class CheckError_Test(BaseTest):
    def test_me(self):
        assert self.rev == rev
```

in base_test.py:

```
import unittest

def triggerSomething(text):
    print "revision was set to",  text

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        p4rev = getattr(self, 'rev')
        triggerSomething(p4rev)
```

shell output:

$ nosetests my_test.py --pdb -s

```
revision was set to 12345
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `BaseTest` an abstract class which requires instances of derived classes to have `self.p4rev` set.

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    # Note: subclasses must provide the p4rev attribute
    def setUp(self):
        triggerSomething(self.p4rev)
```

Then in your test script

```
from BaseTest import BaseTest

rev = '12345'

class CheckError_Test(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        self.p4rev = rev
        BaseTest.setUp(self)  # Or use super() if you like
```

You could optionally use the `ABCMeta` class to mark `BaseTest` as an abstract class more clearly, and define `p4rev` as an abstract property.

I'm pretty sure there are ways to make `nose` use a customer `TestLoader` to instantiate your tests, but this seems to me a simpler alternative.