# Python Unittest case failing in jupyter notebook, but running alright in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spyder, python-unittest

I am new to testing in python and I was trying to work on this code in Jupyter notebook, and it keeps on showing failed, ever if the cases are correct.
But I tried to run the same code in Spyder and it worked alright and gave me the correct output.

tried running this code in jupyter notebook:

```
def add(n,m):
    return n+m
def mul(a,b):
    return a*b

import unittest
class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase): #child of TestCase
    
    def testadd(self):
        self.assertEqual(add(5,5),10) #when we pass, 5 n 5 it should return 10
    def testmul(self):
        self.assertEqual(mul(5,7),35)
if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It gives me the error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: C:\Users\ank (unittest.loader._FailedTest.C:\Users\ank)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'C:\Users\ank'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: True
```

The same code when I ran in Spyder it works just fine and giving me the correct output:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

Is there something I need to fix in my Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, it's no need to fix your jupyter notebook,
as the combination of jupyter and unittest's implmentation leads to unittest incorrect working in jupyter.

---

*The following is added on the next day:*
If you want one that can work in both Jupyter and Spyter (or others),
see answers of
[Unable to run unittest's main function in ipython/jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895781/unable-to-run-unittests-main-function-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook),
which, despite its label `python-2.7`, is fully compatible with python3

Comment: So is there no way that this can work in jupyter?

Comment: I'll give lit the benefit of the doubt that maybe they ran out of time to give a thorough answer. The problem you have having is that your implementation of `unittest.main()` is flawed. Unittest works in Jupyter and even JupyterLab. I need to put code, and so I'll add an answer expanding on this.

Comment: Let me know if that same code I posted works in Spyder. I don't have it easily accessible to see if what works for the `unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=2, exit=False);` line works in Spyder or if you indeed need it different for each.

Comment: @Wayne yeah surely it works!(in Spyder or somewhere else)

Comment: Also, just now I've found there was already Q&A years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895781/unable-to-run-unittests-main-function-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook, (though with label `python-2.7`, it can fully apply to python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Unittest works in a Jupyter `.ipynb` and even run inside JupyterLab. I'm testing and seeing my variation on your code working there fine. I'm basing my variation on [this answer here for the post 'Unit tests for functions in a Jupyter notebook?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405555/8508004). It just seemed your implementation of the `unittest.main()` was flawed.

This is a single cell in a notebook works well:

```py
def add(n,m):
    return n+m
def mul(a,b):
    return a*b

import unittest
class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase): #child of TestCase
    
    def testadd(self):
        self.assertEqual(add(5,5),10) #when we pass, 5 n 5 it should return 10
    def testmul(self):
        self.assertEqual(mul(5,7),35)
if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=2, exit=False);
```

The only thing I changed was the last line, where OP had `unittest.main()`.