# TypeError: unbound method test_logn() must be called with LoginPage instance as first argument (got CompanyManagement instance instead)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

(I am beginner in python)
I have a base class. Inheriting base class, login.py runs without any problem. But when I run Company_Management.py its giving me error TypeError: unbound method test_logn() must be called with LoginPage instance as first argument (got CompanyManagement instance instead)

What I am trying to do is that, when I will run Company_Management.py it will excute test_logn(self) method first then will click on 2 urls from xpath.

### base.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(inst):
        inst.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/chromedriver')    

    @classmethod 
    def tearDownClass(inst):
        inst.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### login.py

```
import base
import unittest
import time

class LoginPage(base.Login):

    def test_logn(self):
        driver =self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.car.com/login?back_url=%2F")

        driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("key@gmail.com")         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### Company_Management.py

```
import base
import unittest
import time
import login

class CompanyManagement(base.Login):
    def test_company(self):

        driver =self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.car.com/login?back_url=%2F")

        Login_test = login.LoginPage.test_logn(self)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ec-ui-side-bar/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ec-ui-side-bar/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li/a/span").click()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in line `Login_test = login.LoginPage.test_logn(self)`, `self` represent object of class in which it belongs, means object of `CompanyManagement`. That's why you are getting error `got CompanyManagement instance instead)`

for calling `test_logn` you need object of class `LoginPage`. You can call it like:

```
from login import LoginPage

class CompanyManagement(base.Login):
    def test_company(self):
    driver =self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.car.com/login?back_url=%2F")

    Login_test = LoginPage().test_logn()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried your solution to. But its giving me another error :

    File "/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/Copell/copell/Company_Management.py", line 26, in test_company

    Login_test = LoginPage().test_logn()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 189, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))

    ValueError: no such test method in <class 'copell.login.LoginPage'>: runTest

Comment: just add and empty method `runTest()` under  `class TestCase` in `case.py` file.  refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090479/valueerror-no-such-test-method-in-class-myapp-tests-sessiontestcase-runtes#answer-28612437)